# I need help for a specific sql task

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been given the following task: I have to write a stored procedure with two parameters: `@Court int, @ReportId NVARCHAR(400)` and i have to split the `@ReportId` parameter by space, convert each piece (of `@ReportId`) into int and use both this piece and the `@Court` parameter to perform an insert operation like this:

```
insert into RPT_Report2court (Reportid, courtnumber)
    values (@ReportId, @Court)
```

for each piece (converted to int) of `@ReportId` parameter.

So far i have done the following:

```
SELECT CAST(value AS int)  
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ReportId, ' ')
```

but i really don't know how to iterate over these int values and take them to use them for the insert statements. (If the language is C# and not SQL i would put these int values in a list of ints and simply iterate over that list with foreach, but i don't know how to do that using sql).

Comment: The syntax suggests SQL Server, so I added the tag.

Comment: And now you want us to do your work task?

Comment: If you are passing the data from c#, I would suggest using a table valued parameter instead of passing a delimited string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create UserDefined function Split.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))        
returns @temptable TABLE (SplitValue varchar(8000))        
as        
begin        
    declare @idx int        
    declare @slice varchar(8000)        

    select @idx = 1        
       if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return        

    while @idx!= 0        
    begin        
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)        
        if @idx!=0        
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)        
        else        
            set @slice = @String        

        if(len(@slice)>0)   
            insert into @temptable(SplitValue) values(@slice)        

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)        
        if len(@String) = 0 break        
    end    
return       
end


insert into RPT_Report2court (Reportid, courtnumber)
select * ,@Court FROM dbo.Split(ReportId,' ')
```

Let me know if you have any query .
Thanks .

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I first tried this query: insert into RPT_Report2court (Reportid, courtnumber)
    select cast(value AS int) , @Court 
    from string_split(@ReportId, ' ');

Comment: but encountered a problem with string_split function. Then i slightly modified your function and it helped me for my problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
insert into RPT_Report2court (Reportid, courtnumber)
    select cast(value AS int) , @Court 
    from string_split(@ReportId, ' ');
```

Comment: Yes, it is, but when i tried to execute this query i encountered a problem with the "string_split" function and i had to find my own way to split the string parameter. Anyway, thanks for the help